# How to see the keychain for iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, keychain

I have developed an iPhone application in which I am encrypting and decrypting data using public and private key. I want to see this keys in  the Keychain. I got the keychain entry for mac applications under Applications/utilities, but what is the location for iPhone simulator Keychain and Keychain for iPhone OS itself on device.

Answer (score 48):

The iPhone simulator keychain is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<Version Number>/Library/Keychains/` and is in sqlite3 DB format. The location of the file on the device itself is unimportant, as you can only access it through the keychain API (but a path with a few similarities to the simulator path wouldn't surprise anyone).

Comment: Starting with iPhone SDK 3.2, the simulator data is stored in separate directories for each OS version inside `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`. For instance if it's the 3.0 simulator that's running, the keychain will be stored in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Library/Keychains`.

Comment: I dont have any iphone simulator folder in application support... what am i suppose to do now

Comment: Have a look at the script charles proxy uses to install it's CA into the simulator keychain it's pretty cool. http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ http://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/install-charles-ca-cert-for-iphone-simulator.zip

Comment: What is the command to access this via keychain.  Can I see it in the keychain application?

Comment: Starting with iOS 8 SDK, you can find keychains in the `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<Simulator Device ID>/data/Library/Keychains`

Comment: I can see the keychain in the path, but even after saving information in keychain, I find that the keychain-2.db debug file's timestamp is not updated. Any idea as to which file to see and confirm that data saved, in iOS simulator.

Answer (score -9):

You must acces the keychain through the keychain API, just like explained in [this](http://dev-metal.blogspot.com/2010/08/howto-use-keychain-in-iphone-sdk-to.html) example.