# Can we get the path of an item stored in Keychain?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

As in sumulator can we get the path of an item stored in Keychain from an iPhone device?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is "path of an item stored in Keychain"? AFAIK, on iOS, Keychain items do not have path, they are identified by service/account (and, internally, by application's BundleID).

Comment: Same as in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636506/how-to-see-the-keychain-for-iphone-simulator .. Can we get the path of the keychains from iPhone

Comment: On iOS, Keychain file is a SQLite3 database stored at `/var/Keychains/Keychain-2.db`. Be advised though that this file is not accessible to normal apps due to sandboxing.